# How to take as much space as they can in flex wrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I created custom input that looks like this:

```
 <div className="custom-input-container">
            <label className="custom-input-label" htmlFor="input">Name</label>
            <input type="email" className="custom-input" id="input"  placeholder="Insert your name</input>
    </div>

.custom-input-container {
    min-width: 300px;

    .custom-input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 56px;
     }
}
```

I'm trying to create a layout with 2 rows. first row with two inputs that should take the whole available space, and second-row where the input should take half on the available space.

I tried to implement this, without success with flex & flex-wrap(still taking only 300px, flex-basis didn't help either).

```
 <div className="billing-details-container flex flex-wrap">
                        <CustomInput />
                        <CustomInput />
                        <CustomInput />
                    </div>

  .billing-details-container {

        & > *:first-child {
            margin-bottom: 24px;
            margin-right: 16px;
        }

        & > *:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
    }
```

Any idea how can I implement this?s?

Comment: @isherwood I just created some helpers, flex is basically ```display: flex``` and flex-wrap is ```flex-wrap:wrap```

Comment: That seems highly relevant to your question. Put it up there, please. You should also create working snippets with your code. Avoid the custom components for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get properly what you are trying to achieve but as much as I have understood the problem, I have made some  changes

```
<div class="custom-input-container">
            <label className="custom-input-label" htmlFor="input">Name</label>
            <input type="email" class="custom-input" id="input"  placeholder="Insert your name"</input>
    </div>

.custom-input-container {
    min-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.custom-input {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    height: 56px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems in your code.

1. You are trying to give classes to html by adding ClassName=""
   The correct syntax is actually class=""
2. You have not closed your second input.

<input type="email" className="custom-input" id="input"  placeholder="Insert your name

Should be

<input type="email" class="custom-input" id="input" placeholder=">Insert your name

You also do not need the  tag.
Why did you give the inputs a specific id?

3. You can not use a label for="" for an input with an id. You should give it a name to use it in the label.

This is code I written. I hope this is what u meant, I removed your label since you are using placeholders anyway. You can add it back yourself if you want.

// ******************** START HTML ******************** //

```
    <div class="custom-input-container">
        <div class='input-group'>
            <input type="email" name="input" placeholder="Insert your name">
            <input type="email" name="input" placeholder="Insert your name">
        </div>
        <input type="email" name="input" placeholder="Insert your name">
    </div>
```

// ******************** END HTML ******************** //
// ******************** START CSS ******************** //

```
    .custom-input-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 300px;
        background: orange;
    }
    .custom-input-container .input-group {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .custom-input-container .input-group input {
        width: 50%;
        height: 56px;
    }
    .custom-input-container input {
        height: 56px;
    }
```

// ******************** END CSS ******************** //